# HttpException not displaying same results in get and post methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

How do you throw an HttpException in a get and post method method with the same results?

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` running on `IIS 7.5`. I am trying to figure the follow scenario on throwing `HttpException` in an `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` action method. I am hoping that someone can help share their view on the matter.

I have the following 2 action methods. This one handles the HttpGet:

```
public ActionResult Logon()
{
     throw new HttpException(401, "brendan's test message");
}
```

And this one handles the HttpPost:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logon(LogonViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
     throw new HttpException(401, "brendan's test message");
}
```

This is how I handle my errors in my global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
     Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
     HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
     Response.Clear();
     Server.ClearError();

     RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
     routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
     routeData.Values["action"] = "Http500";
     routeData.Values["exception"] = httpException;
     Response.StatusCode = 500;
     if (httpException != null)
     {
          Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
          switch (Response.StatusCode)
          {
               case 401:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http401";
                    break;
               case 403:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
                    break;
               case 404:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                    break;
          }
     }

     IController errorController = new ErrorController();
     RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
     errorController.Execute(requestContext);
}
```

And here is my ErrorController class:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Http401()
     {
          return View();
     }

     public ActionResult Http500()
     {
          return View();
     }
}
```

I have nothing configured for errors in my `web.config`.

Here is my view. I have taken out the textboxes:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Logon", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
{
     <p class="buttons">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logon</button>
     </p>
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have my current error pages served on the current URL.

When I run the HttpGet action method my error page is displayed perfectly. When I clicked the button to go into the HttpPost action method then nothing happens. I am expecting the 401 error page to display but it doesn't. Just the current page is displayed. The flow is the same as the get method, it goes all the way to the error controller's view method.

What is the difference between throwing an HttpException in a get and post method?

Comment: How are you issuing the POST request? Can you show your view/form?

Comment: @AntP I have updated my answer. I took out the textboxes as well.

Comment: What action is hit when you POST the form? Does your Application_Error get called? What is the flow in there? Does your page have a single form?

Comment: @CodeCaster Nothing is different. It goes in the error controller after being caught in Application_Error(). Yes it is a single form.

Comment: did you make sure, `httpException.GetHttpCode();` returns same value in both cases? please debug, and make sure once

Comment: Have you confirmed that the throw statement in the HttpPost method is reached? If your posted parameters are wrong then you may have a different exception and the method body is never executed.

Comment: @Zeeshan Yes the 401 error code is returned. I just checked it.

Comment: @AndyNichols Yes it is reached.

Comment: Maybe it's that the new request context you are creating is created using the old context so the verb is still POST. Instead of errorController.Execute(requestContext) maybe don't create the requestContext and instead errorController.RedirectToRoute. I'm not sure this is the issue or it will work (hence a comment rather than an answer) but if you are still stuck it's worth trying.